# Facebook php-sdk writing in response body

Tags: php, symfony, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem with the **Facebook php-sdk-v4**.
I have a back-end server using **Symfony2** and a mobile application as a client.
For authentication, I use the **FOSOAuthServerBundle**.
I try to use Facebook Login in my mobile app.

To authenticate the user in the mobile app, I use the **Android (or IOS) Facebook SDK** and retrieve a **facebook_access_token** and the **facebook_userID**.

I send them to the server where I check if the **facebook_access_token** is valid with this code where `$socialToken` is the **facebook_access_token** receive from the mobile app and `$socialId` is the **facebook_userID** receive from the mobile app :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id'  => self::FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => self::FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
    'default_access_token' => $socialToken
));
$result = $facebook->get('/me');
$this->socialDetails = $result->getGraphUser();
if ($this->socialDetails->getId() != $socialId) {
    $this->logger->info("checkFacebookAccessToken : Token is NOT valid");
    return false;
}
$this->logger->info("checkFacebookAccessToken : Token is valid");
return true;
```

This code is working fine.
Once the token validated, I forward the request to the **FOSOAuthServerController** to generate an access token and return this access_token to the mobile app with :

```
return $response = $this->get('fos_oauth_server.controller.token')->tokenAction($request);
```

This code is working too.
But the problem is that the response body send to the mobile app is the following :

```
object(Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser)#616 (1) {
     ["items":protected]=>
     array(2) {
         ["name"]=>
             string(16) "John Doe"
         ["id"]=>
             string(15) "123456789012345"
     }
}
{
    "access_token":"myAccessToken",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "scope":null,
    "refresh_token":"myRefreshToken"
}
```

instead of :

```
{
    "access_token":"myAccessToken",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "scope":null,
    "refresh_token":"myRefreshToken"
}
```

It seems that Symfony **appends the 2 responses body**.
But when I log the response return by the FOSOAuthServerBundle controller it only displays the second response.

Maybe the Facebook php-sdk writes directly in the response body. Is there a way to delete the content of the response body before forwarding the request to the FOSOAuthServerBundle controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you forgot a `var_dump($this->socialDetails);` somewhere in your code.